# cannot implicitly convert from type void to Systems.Collections.Generics.List<>

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to add a new object to a list of objects using string.Equals and getting a conversion error as below

Here is my object:

```
public class TestNode : CSVBaseModel
{
    public int DatabaseID { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; } //make object
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StepNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Job JobModel { get; set; }
    public TestNode(int databaseID, string entityType, string name, int stepNumber)
    {
        DatabaseID = databaseID;
        EntityType = entityType;
        Name = name;
        StepNumber = stepNumber;
    }
}
```

And my list:

```
List<TestNode> testNodes = new List<TestNode>();
```

And here is where the error happens (after the colon, in the statement):

```
job.TestNodes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]) ? job.TestNodes : testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0));
```

Can anyone tell me why it wont convert? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

TestNodes is a list property generic to another object. testNodes is a list specific to the byteArray being compiled. I hope that makes sense. Maybe this gives a little better context:

```
private Job ProcessFile2(byte[] filestream)
{
    List<TestNode> testNodes = new List<TestNode>();
    Job job = new Job();
    Guid uniqueRecordId = Guid.NewGuid();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(filestream), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
    DateTime creationDate = DateTime.Now;
    int nodeCounter = 0;

    string line;
    int linecounter = 0;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (linecounter > 1)
        {
            var columns = line.Split(",");
            job.JobName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[1]) ? job.JobName : columns[1];
            job.TestNodes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]) ? job.TestNodes : new List<TestNode> { new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0) };
            job.TestNodes= string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[3]) ? job.TestNodes : testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "OrganisationType", job.OrganisationType, 0));
            job.ContractingOrganisationType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[4]) ? job.ContractingOrganisationType : columns[4];
            job.TestNodes = string.Equals(columns[0], "Job Step") ? testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "StepName", columns[6], Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]))) : job.TestNodes;
            job.TestNodes = string.Equals(columns[0], "Custom Input") ? testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "InputName", columns[6], Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]))) : job.TestNodes;
            job.TestNodes = string.Equals(columns[0], "Custom Output") ? testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "OutputName", columns[6], Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]))) : job.TestNodes;
            job.TestNodes = string.Equals(columns[0], "Generic Input") ? testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "GenericInputName", columns[6], Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]))) : job.TestNodes;
            job.Record = uniqueRecordId;
            job.CreationDate = creationDate;
            job.ModificationDate = creationDate;
            job.CreateBy = "System";
            job.ModifyBy = "System";
        }
        linecounter++;
    }
    return job;
}
```

Comment: `List<>.Add()` has a `void` return type.  Instead of assigning `job.TestNodes` to itself in the `true` branch of the ternary operator it seems like it'd be better to use an `if` block.

Comment: I see. Is there some sort of work around for that?

Comment: `job.TestNodes = testNodes;`?  If you were expecting `testNodes.Add(...)` to return the added node that wouldn't make sense (or compile) to assign it to `job.TestNodes`, which I assume is some collection of `TestNode`s.

Comment: Would you mind showing how i would rework the whole statement? I'm a little new to this

Comment: TestNodes is a list property generic to another object. testNodes is a list specific to the byteArray being compiled. I hope that makes sense. Maybe this gives a little better context:                                                                                                      private Job ProcessFile2(byte[] filestream)
        {
            List<TestNode> testNodes = new List<TestNode>();
            Job job = new Job();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the ternary operator...

```cs
job.TestNodes = string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]) ? job.TestNodes : testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0));
```

...effectively works like this...

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]))
{
    job.TestNodes = job.TestNodes;
}
else
{
    job.TestNodes = testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0));
}
```

The [`List<>.Add()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add) has this signature...

```cs
public void Add (T item);
```

`void` means it doesn't return anything.  You can't assign the result of a `void` method to some other storage because there is no result to assign.  (Note that this is different than a method that happens to return `null`.)

To fix this, perform your call to `Add()` and subsequent `List<>` assignment separately...

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]))
{
    job.TestNodes = job.TestNodes;
}
else
{
    testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0));
    job.TestNodes = testNodes;
}
```

Since the `true` branch of the `if` block is effectively a no-op, we can rewrite that as simply...

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]))
{
    testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0));
    job.TestNodes = testNodes;
}
```

Depending on how `job.TestNodes` gets assigned it might be necessary to instead do...

```cs
job.TestNodes = testNodes;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[2]))
{
    testNodes.Add(new TestNode(nodeCounter += 1, "JobExecutor", columns[2], 0));
}
```